# Spring Boot and Angular giving Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Tags: spring-boot, angular5

I am learning Spring boot with Angular, and I am trying to get my first app up and running reading the following blogs:

http://mydevgeek.com/angular-4-crud-application-with-spring-boot-rest-service-part-2/

https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-basic-crud-app-with-angular-50-and-spring

I manage to get the app working using spring boot on the 8080 port, and it works as expected. However, when I try to get it to work with Angular, I get the following error:

```
    Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
core.js:3675
ERROR 
{…}
error: error
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest
__zone_symbol__errorfalse: null
__zone_symbol__loadfalse: null
__zone_symbol__xhrListener: function scheduleTask/target[XHR_LISTENER]()
__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false
__zone_symbol__xhrTask: Object { runCount: 0, _state: "notScheduled", type: "macroTask", … }
__zone_symbol__xhrURL: "//localhost:8080/cool-cars"
mozAnon: false
mozSystem: false
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: "text"
responseURL: ""
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {  }
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequestPrototype { open: patchMethod/proto[name](), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), send: patchMethod/proto[name](), … }
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest
__zone_symbol__errorfalse: null
__zone_symbol__loadfalse: null
__zone_symbol__xhrListener: function scheduleTask/target[XHR_LISTENER]()
__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false
__zone_symbol__xhrTask: Object { runCount: 0, _state: "notScheduled", type: "macroTask", … }
__zone_symbol__xhrURL: "//localhost:8080/cool-cars"
mozAnon: false
mozSystem: false
readyState: 4
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: "text"
responseURL: ""
status: 0
statusText: ""
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {  }
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequestPrototype { open: patchMethod/proto[name](), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), send: patchMethod/proto[name](), … }
target: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "//localhost:8080/cool-cars", readyState: 4, … }
timeStamp: 5395.150856236699
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEventPrototype { lengthComputable: Getter, loaded: Getter, total: Getter, … }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map }
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse() }
```

When I look at the network tab, I see the following information:

Header: 
Accept
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection
keep-alive
Host
localhost:8080

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/cool-cars
Request Method: GET

But there is no response. It seems the request times out.

The Chrome network tab shows this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/cool-cars
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36
```

My Java classes:

Car class:

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode

public class Car {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private @NonNull String name;

}
```

Car repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long>  {


}
```

Controller:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CoolCarController {

    private CarRepository repository;

    public CoolCarController(CarRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/cool-cars")
    public Collection<Car> coolCars() {

        return repository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(this::isCool)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private boolean isCool(Car car) {
        return !car.getName().equals("AMC Gremlin") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Triumph Stag") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Ford Pinto") &&
                !car.getName().equals("Yugo GV");
    }
}
```

App class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        ApplicationRunner init(CarRepository repository) {

            return args -> {

                Stream.of("Ferrari", "Jaguar", "Porsche", "Lamborghini", "Bugatti",

                        "AMC Gremlin", "Triumph Stag", "Ford Pinto", "Yugo GV").forEach(name -> {

                    Car car = new Car();

                    car.setName(name);

                    repository.save(car);

                });

                repository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);

            };

        }

    }
```

As you can see, the CORS is enable with annotations.

In Angular, I have made the following changes.

car.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class CarService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('//localhost:8080/cool-cars');
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CarService } from './shared/car/car.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CarListComponent} from "./car-list/car-list.component";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [CarService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

car list component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService } from '../shared/car/car.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-list',
  templateUrl: './car-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-list.component.css']
})
export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {

  cars: Array<any>;

  constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.cars = data;
    });
  }

}
```

car list component html

```
<h2>Car List</h2>

<div *ngFor="let car of cars">

  {{car.name}}

</div>
```

I am using IntelliJ.

I have read a lot about this issue, including similar questions on this topic, but I did not see an answer that could resolve this issue (and that had the same empty response). Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: In my example, I had `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` next to `@GetMapping("/cool-cars")`, rather than on the class itself. Can you try moving it and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Matt, I have tried it as well and it does not work. I still get the "get" request to cool-car returning empty or timing out... :(

Comment: I would suggest cloning my completed project (https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-5-example) from GitHub then using something like SmartSynchronize (http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize) or Beyond Compare (https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) to compare the two projects and look for differences. Make sure to exclude node_modules when you do. I'm guessing it might be the last step of adding a `simpleCorsFilter` in `DemoApplication.java`.

Comment: I have done it, and I am getting a similar issue: cars are not showing and I cannot add a new car. But the network tab of my browser shows something slightly different: status 302, and the cause is: "CORS header « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » missing.". It is very odd, as everything in the spring boot part of the code is done to add a CORS header...

Comment: Can you publish your project to GitHub so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Spring Boot app with HTTP PUT API works fine when tested from Postman. But, when same API is called from Angular 5.2.4, I'm seeing a 200 response but with empty body in the network log and "message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" from catch block of Angular's HTTP PUT's subscription method.

Comment: Solved! Issue was with some response headers. I was actually propagating the headers from an external API, once I removed the response headers, it worked fine.